# MySQL 入れ子集合モデル、子から見た親を出力する方法

Tags: mysql

MySQL入れ子集合モデルで「子から見た親」を出力する方法なのですが、うまくいきません

下記は、categoryを格納しているテーブルです。

[image: categoryを格納しているテーブルです。]

下記は、子から見た親を出力するクエリです。

```
select node.rgt, concat(repeat(' ', count(parent.category_name) - 1),　node.category_name) as name, node.category_description
from category as node, category as parent 
where node.lft between parent.lft and 4
group by node.category_name order by node.lft;
```

下記は、クエリを実行した結果です。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

実行結果から見ますとうまく言っているのですが、私は実行結果を１行に３列で表示したいです。
どのように考えればうまくいきますか。ご教授よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1):

GROUP_CONCAT を使ってみてはいかがですか。

```
select node.rgt, GROUP_CONCAT(node.category_name SEPARATOR ' ') as name ...
```

GROUP_CONCAT の内部では DISTINCT や ORDER BY を使うことができます。

Comment: ありがとうございます。GROUP_CONCATを使ってみようと思います。

また、実行結果を報告させて頂きます。

Answer (score 0):

入れ子モデルの階層構造データですね。

http://www.geocities.jp/mickindex/database/db_tree_ns.html
このサイトの「2-7．パスを列挙する（列持ちバージョン）」を参照すればうまくいくのではないでしょうか。